# Given an trigonometric sum, extract amplitudes and angles as separate lists

Tags: expression-manipulation

How can I extract amplitudes and angles as separate lists from an trigonometric expression?

Sample input:

$$A_{1} \cos \left(\phi -\frac{2 \pi }{3}\right)+
  A_{2} \cos \left(2 \phi +\frac{\pi }{3}\right)+
  A_{3} \cos \left(3 \phi -\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$$

```
A1 Cos[ϕ - 2 Pi/3] + A2 Cos[2 ϕ + Pi/3] + A3 Cos[3 ϕ - Pi/2]
```

Desired outputs:

1. List of amplitudes: $[A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3}]$ , `{A1,A2,A3}`
2. List of angles: $[\phi -\frac{2 \pi}{3}, 2 \phi +\frac{\pi}{3}, 3 \phi -\frac{\pi}{2}]$ `{ϕ - 2 Pi/3,2 ϕ + Pi/3,3 ϕ - Pi/2}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
exp = A1 Cos[ϕ - 2 Pi/3] + A2 Cos[2 ϕ + Pi/3] + A3 Cos[3 ϕ - Pi/2] // HoldForm

{amplitudes, angles} = Transpose[exp /. {Plus -> List} /. {A_*Cos[phi_] :> {A, 
     Total@phi}} // ReleaseHold]
(*{{A1, A2, A3}, {-((2 π)/3) + ϕ, π/3 + 2 ϕ, -(π/2) + 3 ϕ}}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exp = Sum[ RandomReal[] Cos[RandomReal[] ϕ + RandomReal[]], {k, 10}]
```

> ```
> 0.58841 Cos[0.255484 + 0.116817 ϕ] + 
>  0.410137 Cos[0.606744 + 0.187887 ϕ] + 
>  0.0087033 Cos[0.267439 + 0.220191 ϕ] + 
>  0.231662 Cos[0.389939 + 0.232118 ϕ] + 
>  0.851933 Cos[0.0605113 + 0.275988 ϕ] + 
>  0.127151 Cos[0.724798 + 0.316905 ϕ] + 
>  0.587836 Cos[0.0236456 + 0.371794 ϕ] + 
>  0.453645 Cos[0.459396 + 0.440963 ϕ] + 
>  0.55557 Cos[0.623873 + 0.71966 ϕ] + 
>  0.588512 Cos[0.0700004 + 0.939417 ϕ]
> ```

```
{amplitudes, angles} = Transpose@Cases[exp, Times[a_, Cos[b_]] ->  {a, b}]
```

OR

```
ReplaceAll[List @@ exp,
 {
  Times[a_, Sin[b_]] -> {a, π/2 - b},
  Times[a_, Cos[b_]] -> {a, b}
  }]
```